# NetBeans: 7.4 plugins

Tags: netbeans, jmeter

I am trying to install JMeter in Netbeans 7.4:

```
 Tools > Plugins > Available Plugins
```

Load Generator appears,but no JMeter.

How do you load JMeter into Netbeans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, as visible on the web, the Official JMeter Plugin Downloader hasn't been released for Netbeans 7.4. It's still available only for Netbeans IDE 7.3. Hence you aren't getting the JMeter Plugin in the list of Available Plugins in your updated IDE!

[image: Details Of JMeter Plugin]

So, you better download it from the link **[JMeter-Netbeans Plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/49923/jmeter)**

```
Tools > Plugins > Downloaded > "Selecting your downloaded plugin by choosing the Location".
```

If it works,well and good. If it doesn't, then sorry. I detailed whatever I knew!